# Apply Shape Key to Armature

Tags: modeling, armature, shape-keys

I have a model with an armature rig to pose in different poses. I then have various items/clothing which can be equipped and they follow the mesh using an armature modifier/weight paints.

I am working a shape key to adjust the height of the model (shorter/taller). Since the actual armature is not changed, the items do not go to the correct location and the poses are deformed due to the change in vertex location to the bone.

I am including a screencap that has the working armature/pose and then the deformed one where I am attempting to use a shape key to change the size of the model.

In my mind there would ideally be a slider similar to shape keys which would allow me to shrink/stretch my armature to match what I am doing with my model. Or does anyone have a suggestion on how I can better implement this? Thank you for your time!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use scaling of a bone (say one of the spine bones) to make your character taller. If the child bones also scale and that is not what you want, just uncheck the 'inherit scale' in the bone properties. The parented meshes will follow the enlarged character as well.