# Using shape keys change height and torse of human body

Tags: armature, shape-keys

I have created rigged avatar(.glb) along with multiple meshes like shirt, trousers etc
need to change the avatar Height by which body shape should change accordingly.

Using Shape keys, by selecting the relavant mesh able to change the mesh width but armature is not changing accordingly.
pls suggest some solution for this

I tried with this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127974/apply-shape-key-to-armature) but no luck

[my avatar attachment](https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/idletshirt4.glb)

Thanks
vijay

Comment: Is your character supposed to get bigger or taller? Maybe tell a bit more, show some screenshots, etc, there are several solutions, depending on your needs...

Comment: Yeah, don't use shapekeys for this.  Scale your bones instead.  If you are using in some other application, then your posing will probably need to occur in that application.

Comment: can u share some video/link upon the approach. edited the question by attaching avatar link

Comment: thanks for the file but it doesn't help to guess what kind of scaling you want to do, as Nathan says if you plan to scale your character up, then scale the bones in Pose mode?

Comment: In my case am using babylonjs as the rendering engine, i need to adjust the height and weight of the body simultaneously from web.  can i use Morph targets for this, could u pls share some help link